# Issue attempting a wp_query_posts with tags

Tags: wp-query, query, tags, post-type

Having an issue trying to query the most recent posts using the tag, in this case, trending. I used the following code but I get no results. If I switch out 'tag' to 'post_type' it will work:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'tag' => 'trending',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
);
$queryone = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php while ($queryone -> have_posts()) : $queryone -> the_post(); ?>
<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
<div class="feature" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) no-repeat top center!important; background-size: cover!important;">
<div class="feature-bottom"><h3><?php echo get_post_type( $post ) ?></h3><h2><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?> </h2></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. In my args, I should have included this line:

```
'post_type' => array( 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six' ),
```

above the 'tag' arguments